# Binary file refuses to run due to a missing shared library

Tags: configuration, build, makefile, shared-libraries

I tried building [recutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/) version 1.7 downloaded from the home page, using the standard `configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` sequence, but when trying to run the resulting binaries. like `recinf`, I get the error:

```
recinf: error while loading shared libraries: librec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean I made a mistake during the build or is the package itself in error?

Comment: It probably just means you need to run `ldconfig` as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Etan Reisner said the problem was that the shared object libraries were installed but not loaded into the cache, hence the need to run `ldconfig`. After running

```
sudo ldconfig
```

the binaries ran properly. If I had looked in /usr/local/lib, I would have seen the libs there.